# Terminal: can I configure the OPEN command to associate specific file extensions/types with specified applications?

Tags: zsh

Basically the full question is in the title already:
can I configure the OPEN command to associate specific file extensions/types with specified applications?

Comment: The `open` command already does this for extensions and file types configured by default and [via Finder](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/choose-an-app-to-open-a-file-on-mac-mh35597/mac) - see `man open`. Are you trying to have `open` behave differently than Finder?

Comment: Thanks, no, I didn't know I could do it through Finder